# Jquery Datatables OnSort update column with figure from another column

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a table that is running as Jquery datatable. I have the following requirement

When a user sorts on a column then

1. I need to indentify the column
2. Depending on this sort column I want to get a value from another column which is invisible to the user
3. With this value I  want to update the first column in the table. This is a visible column

I have bound a sort event to the table with a function called eventFired as per the example on 
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html

The best I could get myself is below

```
 function eventFired( type ) {     
          var oTable = $('#tabOverlayLeagueTable').dataTable(); //select table
          var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings(); //get settings
          var sortByindex = oSettings.aaSorting[0][0];//get index of sort column
          //var nNodes = oTable.fnGetNodes( ); // I am not sure if I should use this 
          var data = oTable.fnGetData( ); // I get the data from this call

          // loop then data rows
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

               // update the first column in the table
              // with a specific column (this is a hidden column). In 
              //example its cashiers rank figure
              oTable.fnUpdate( data[i].CashierRank, i, 0);
          }             
 }
```

Problem

1. This might not be the best way of solving my problem
2. I would to get the column `data[i].CashierRank` by index rather than name
3. The code doesn't work. Seems to loop forever!

Answer (score 0):

i hope that this helps

**problem 1**:
Intuitively I would say that is better to update the whole table when you finish all the data modifications, just once.

**problem 2:**
You can get the name of the property by index accessing to the columns description:

```
var colName = oSettings.aoColumns[sortByindex].mData
```

**problem 3:**
That's weird. This is a simple for, so... 
When you say that it loops forever you mean that the index tend to infinite, not stopping at the length?? I think that maybe you are executing this function each time the table does a render, o that the table thinks it's being sorted when you update those columns. In that case you are creating an infinite loop because you call the render inside the for (with fnUpdate), and updating the whole table after change all the values as I said in the 1. it should be solved.